# Why would adding a delegate to a UINavigationController crash my app?

Tags: iphone, delegates, storyboard

I'm working on an iPhone application. I'm using Storyboard.

I wanted to have one object attached to the NavController to handle the visibility of the button bar at the bottom of windows that display table views.

I created my own  UINavigationDelegate; MyNavigationControllerDelegate.

I have created an NSObject in UIBuilder and changed its class MyNavigationControllerDelegate. And then attached it as the delegate of the UINavigationController.

[image]

For some reason  MyNavigationControllerDelegate is getting deallocated.  I would have thought that being the delegate would be enough to keep a reference to it and prevent deallocation, but that seems not to be the case.

Any suggestions as to how to prevent it from being deallocated? And do I have to reset it as the delegate each time a view is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delegate` property of UINavigationController is declared as `assign` rather than `retain` or `strong` (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/delegate)). Delegates are typically declared either `weak` or `assign`, which means assigning the property will not cause the `UINavigationController` to increase the reference count on your delegate, and you need another object to hold a strong reference to it (perhaps your RootViewController).